# Change string by condition Assembler

Tags: if-statement, assembly, compare

```
lea ebx, ss:[ebp-0x118] 
This code adds [ebp-0x118](str1...123456)   to EBX 0014EF18
This address has hex data 73 74 72 31 00 00 00 31 32 33 34 35 36(str1...123456)
```

The EBX register has the address where the string is stored (str1...123456). I need to compare the first four characters of String1 with String2.
If they are equal, then change the String1 to String3.
if 'str1'=String 2 then str1=String3.(str1 is first four characters of the Srting1)
Assembler is studying recently. I would be very grateful if you help me figure it out.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: I updated my quastion. Could you look again?

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable.

Comment: do you want to replace str1 in-place with string3, i.e. overwrite original memory content at `0014EF18`, or is it enough just to replace the address in `ebx` with address of `string3`, keeping the memory at `0014EF18` without change? If in-place, do you want to replace only 4 characters of str1, or copy whole string3? What if it does not fit?

Answer (score 0):

4 bytes is a convenient special-case: you can use `cmp [ebx], 'str2'` / `jne nomatch` to do one dword compare, instead of looping over bytes.